# How to add parameters to Firebase dynamic links in react native?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-dynamic-links

I am trying to create a functionality where a user can share deep links from my app. But for some reason, I am unable to pass dynamic parameters to my deep link. On my listener code, i am not getting the link that I passed in the build link but I am getting the link that is stored in my firebase console deep link URL.

Code while building link

```
const link = await dynamicLinks().buildShortLink({
    link: 'https://astro.page.link/Profile?type='+type,
    // domainUriPrefix is created in your Firebase console
    domainUriPrefix: 'https://astro.page.link',
    // optional setup which updates Firebase analytics campaign
    // "banner". This also needs setting up before hand
    navigation:{

    },
    analytics: {
      campaign: 'banner',
    },
  });
```

Code while listening for link

```
dynamicLinks()
.getInitialLink()
.then(link => {
  
    console.log(link);
    alert(link.url);
});
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: looks like: `Const link.link` Try `alert(link.link.url)`

Comment: Doing that gives me error `Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'link.link.url')`